# Is it possible to return a Mono.just("index") from a GetMapping("/") handler?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Let's consider this request handler:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public Mono<String> index(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("list", Flux.just("item1", "item2"));
  return Mono.just("list"); // <- Template name
}
```

If there is an `index.html` template in the `templates` directory, this handler is not excuted.

If I  return `Mono.just("index")` from the handler:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public Mono<String> index(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("list", Flux.just("item1", "item2"));
  return Mono.just("index"); // <- Template name
}
```

This handler is still not used.

It seems like I have to remove the `index.html` template from the `templates` directory for the `GetMapping("/")` route to be handled.

So my question is, is it possible to return a `Mono.just("index")` from a `GetMapping("/")` handler ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this [book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Fv1wDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=reactive%20getmapping%20handler%20html%20template&source=bl&ots=81gwuGFH-0&sig=ACfU3U0k55zS71dQ3N8-eid6Twh1_f3jtA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjs-q6f8KfqAhVR4jgGHTMzA9gQ6AEwA3oECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=reactive%20getmapping%20handler%20html%20template&f=false), you should use @Controller instead of @RestController.

And here is another sample:

```
@GetMapping("/welcome")
    public Mono<String> hello(final Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", "Foo");
        model.addAttribute("city", "Bar");

        String path = "hello";
        return Mono.create(monoSink -> monoSink.success(path));
    }
```

The corresponding thymeleaf html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Greet</title>
</head>

<body>

<p th:text="${name}"></p> lives in <p th:text="${city}"></p> 

</body>
</html>
```